# ora:00936 Missing Expression error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting ORA:00936 error for the following query.Please let me know the issue in the query

```
SELECT convert(DATE,r.created_dt) as created_dt,
r.created_dt as time,
r.rep_id,
rt.rep_type_id,
rt.rep_type_desc
FROM t_tbm_ia_rep_2015 r,
t_tbm_ia_rep_type_2015 rt
WHERE r.rep_type_id=rt.rep_type_id
GROUP BY r.created_dt,
r.rep_id,
rt.rep_type_id,
rt.rep_type_desc
ORDER BY rt.rep_type_id
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the r.created_dt? I'm betting that `convert()` is not the function you need. If that column is  VARCHAR2 and you're wanting to convert it into a date, then you should be using `to_date()`. If it's a DATE or TIMESTAMP and you want to display it as a string in a different format, then you should be using `to_char()`. Whichever function you use, you'll need to supply the relevant format mask. (Eg. `select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SELECT convert(DATE,r.created_dt) as created_dt

The issue is with the incorrect use of **CONVERT** function. Please see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm).

```
SQL> SELECT convert(DATE,hiredate) as created_dt from emp;
SELECT convert(DATE,hiredate) as created_dt from emp
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression


SQL>
```

I guess you are trying convert the datatype, you could use **TO_DATE** to convert string into date. Or, **TO_CHAR** to do vice-versa.